# Trying to save a .wav audio file from Nao. I get a damaged file

Tags: python-2.7, wav, wave, nao-robot, naos-project

I am implementing a client capable of capturing an audio file from the Nao robot and sending it via socket to a server locally. In reading the file I get a corrupted audio file

```
if os.path.exists(file_path+"/"+filename):
    audio_file = wave.open(file_path+"/"+filename, 'rb')
    sample_width = audio_file.getsampwidth()
    num_channels = audio_file.getnchannels()
    frame_rate = audio_file.getframerate()
    num_frames = audio_file.getnframes()

    audio_data = audio_file.readframes(num_frames)

    audio_file.close()
else:
    print("Errore: Il file '{}' non esiste.".format(file_path+"/"+filename))
```

From this i expect an audio file in .wav, but i have a .wav corrupted file

Comment: Given that you opened the file with the mode `'rb'`, you are only reading the file here, instead of writing it. Perhaps you forgot to mention how you write the .wav file in the first place? Please also post the actual error message.